# mysql connection from navicat, always return 10086, i have tried a lot, but failed

Tags: mysql, connection

[mysql base info on my server followed：](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tXvBA.jpg)

and i have already grant all to root@'%';

[connect to mysql always show error like this error 10086：](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pI6Ad.jpg)

and i have stop all firewall on server: service iptables stop;

but error still there, very confused, i have try everything i know, mysql is lost my control, anyone who can help me? thanks a lot!!

Comment: navicat on my window system can login other mysql on other servers. so client is fine!

Comment: telnet server 3306 failed

Comment: Is this a new mysql instance?  If so, you might check the my.cnf to see if bind address is set.  If it is, it will only allow connections from localhost (127.0.0.1).  Comment out this line and restart mysql and you should be able to connect.

Comment: bind_address is 0.0.0.0 i tried comment out. error still there.

Comment: if there is a line "skip-networking" comment that out as well.